# how to use sum function when there are multiple rows

Tags: sql

```
MSISDN      Name    y/N     top     cycle   ActivationDate  Bottom  Provisioned  renewdate
78          W1      N       NA       24         3-Apr-15    th4         512     10-Apr-15
78          W1      N       NA       24         3-Apr-15    th5         256     17-Apr-15
78          W1      N       NA       24         3-Apr-15    th2         512     5-Apr-15
79          w2      Y       33       29         4-Apr-15    th5         1024    8-Apr-15
79          w2      Y       33       29         4-Apr-15    th4         2048    8-Apr-15
```

Expected output

```
MSISDN      Name    y/N     top     cycle   ActivationDate  Bottom  Provisioned  renewdate
78          W1      N       NA       24         3-Apr-15    null 1280-2048      null
79          w2      Y       33       29         4-Apr-15    th5         1024            8-Apr-15
79          w2      Y       33       29         4-Apr-15    th4         2048            8-Apr-15
```

when i write a sql i am able to query the sql for NA case grouping based on the name.
can we write a sql to meet the both conditions.when "NA" it has to sum up all the data provisioned

Comment: yes, summing up based on the MSISDN

Comment: How do you determine when to use the value for the other columns versus replacing non-distinct values with `null`?  For example, `Name` stays `W1`, but `Bottom` turns into `null`?  Also, how does the `Provisioned` column sum to 1280-2048?

Comment: If top is "NA", i can show Bottom as null and provisioned is (sum of all the values assigned  to the msisdn in this case 512+512+25i6) and this value should be subtracted from 2048.i.e.,  1280-2048 = 768 (need to show)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a UNION to do this:

```
SELECT MSISDN, Name, y/N, top, cycle, activationDate, NULL, Sum(PRovisioned), Null
FROM <table> 
WHERE top = 'NA'
GROUP BY  MSISDN, Name, y/N, top, cycle, activationDate

UNION ALL

SELECT MSISDN,Name,y/N,top,cycle,ActivationDate,Bottom,Provisioned,renewdate
FROM <table>
WHERE top <> 'NA'
```

That should get you close. I have no idea how you are getting `1280-2048` for your 'Provisioned' in the `GROUP BY` query though. You'll have to explain the logic there for additional help should you need it.